# Google Maps API V3: Create Marker HTML based on search if/else

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I have a "store locator" setup here:

http://www.brynei.com/fertdealer_map_bry.htm

lat, lng, name, address, csz, and phone information is stored in a mySQL database.  If you input zip code 13165, the locator works as it should.  However, I need to limit a range of zip codes to show one marker, and display the marker html for a range of zip codes (66000 to 69999).  This part is actually working to center the map using the function searchLocations() section, but I need some help in the function createMarker(latlng, name, address, csz, phone) and function createOption(name, distance, num) section.

Currently if you use zip code 67501, the map will center but no marker is displayed.  I need it to place a marker in a specific location, and Company Name Inc, 123 Main St, Anywhere KS 67501, 555-555-1234 as the marker HTML.  That marker would be static if a zip is used in the 66000 to 69999 range.

I can do something on the database side also if that is an easier solution.

Any help is appreciated.

These are the 3 sections (functions) I am having an issue with:

```
function searchLocations() {
var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
var mylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.928552, -97.898658);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   if (address >= 66000 && address <= 69999) {
       map.setCenter(mylatlng);
       map.setZoom(10);        }
       else { 
           geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {       
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);   } 
    else {
        alert(address + ' not found');
   }
 });
 }}

function createMarker(latlng, name, address, csz, phone) {
  var html = "<font face = 'arial'>" + "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + csz + "<br/>" + phone + "</font>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
} 


function createOption(name, distance, num) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = num;
  option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
  locationSelect.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: Can you add just the key section of the problem code to your question and be a little more specific about your problem?